# Where does Gozreh live?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, religions-and-deities, planes

Where does the god [Gozreh](http://lacrypte.fr/pathfinder_wiki/index.php?title=Gozreh) live?

His alignment suggests purgatory, but his flavour suggests he would prefer a more natural environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question! Gozreh is said to dwell "at the horizon, where the sea meets the sky" (Gods and Magic, 18). As a result [pathfinderwiki.com](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Gozreh) lists his/her home as the Material Plane.  In his/her more full article in Pathfinder #38, Racing to Ruin, it only notes "Many cloud and storm giants are native to her planar realm," hinting that there is one, but this is a throwaway line not expanded upon.

The Inner Sea Gods hardback is also a great source for detailed information on Gozreh and all the deities. It states "Even the few deities who live in the mortal world (such as Gozreh, whose realm includes any natural place,..." which confirms that the Wind and the Waves dwell here in the mortal realm, wherever there is sky or sea.

Now if you're asking where Gozreh's faithful end up after death that's a different thing, and the answer is usually complicated, see [How is it determined which souls end up in Hell, the Abyss or Abaddon?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59461/how-is-it-determined-which-souls-end-up-in-hell-the-abyss-or-abaddon/59469#59469) for more on that. They would generally go to their alignment-tied planes except in specific cases I'd think.

Comment: So he/she has some physical location as his "home" on the material plane. It kind of seems like he/she is the main deity of the material plane. I wasn't interested in where the faithful go, although now that you bring it up: By alignment the true neutral would go to purgatory permanently, but that seems to be a transition plane. Likewise, the chaotic neutral (like my char) would go to the maelstrom/limbo.

Comment: In The Great Beyond, A Guide to the Multiverse, it states that neutral souls stay in the Boneyard.

Comment: No, only some do, it's been clarified a lot in later works. (The Boneyard is also called Purgatory, hence the OP's question.)

Comment: Which works, if you don't mind my asking? I was specifically saying neutral, not X-neutral.

Comment: See the linked question.